# Question on word order for inverted Sentence structure

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

I have an odd sentence structure that I'm proofing that, for the author's idiosyncratic needs, has to maintain an inverted structure.

The sentence is

> trustworthy must he be who would be allowed our secrets.

I'm inclined to think that the "he" and "be" should be swapped ("trustworthy must be he who would . . . "). My thinking is that "who" attached to "he," not "be." But some of my colleagues think otherwise.  Is there a right or wrong answer here? Thanks!

Comment: If editing while unsure, best not to change it.

Comment: I think it works in either order, although it changes the emphasis. But this whole inversion is somewhat archaic.

Comment: Missing word:  who would be allowed to know our secrets. Obviously. You know someone's secrets or find out someone's secrets. You need a **verb**. Without a verb the meaning is differnt: He was allowed no cake at breakfast.

Comment: @Lambie — *Allowed* means *provided* or *granted* here.

Comment: Don't try to impose modern syntax on literary pieces.

Comment: @TinfoilHat For me, it doesn't matter whether it's provided, granted or allowed. There's still a missing word. "to be allowed our secrets" just doesn't make much sense. allow secrets: The man was not allowed [to have] any secrets. One has secrets or keeps secrets.

Comment: I kinda prefer *who our secrets is allowed*. Double down on the inverted structure?

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable, and the difference is very subtle, perhaps even insignificant.

> Trustworthy must he be who would be allowed our secrets.

means

> Whoever would be allowed our secrets must be trustworthy.

When you swap the words,

> Trustworthy must be he who would be allowed our secrets.

means

> He who would be allowed our secrets must be trustworthy.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re working in scriptural vernacular, it’s fine as is.

A drive-by search on `"he be who"` reveals . . .

[Google All](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he+be+who%22)

[Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he+be+who%22&tbm=bks)

Comment: *A drive-by search on "he be who"*… If these searches do return similar results for most people now (unlikely for main Google search but possible), they certainly won't a year from now. Summarize your point in the answer itself instead of relying on volatile links like that.

Comment: @Laurel — Unless the Bible and other religious tracts disappear from the internets, these links can certainly be relied upon to return relevant results.

Answer (score 0):

- *Trustworthy must he be who would be allowed our secrets.*

shows the inversion and extraposition (CGEL probably prefers 'postposition') from NP one would expect in such a register. But with a non-pronounal subject, especially a heavy one

- *Trustworthy must be that very rare, singularly gifted, and greatly privileged individual who would be allowed our secrets.*

the extraposition (positioning the relative clause immediately after 'be', which itself is placed after the NP) becomes farcical:

- ?*Trustworthy must that very rare, singularly gifted, and greatly privileged individual be who would be allowed our secrets.*

And terminal 'be' is worse.

Answer (score 0):

to **be allowed one's secrets** actually *means*:
to be allowed to have one's secrets.

So, for purposes of clearer prose:

Trustworthy must he be who would be allowed (to know, share, have) our secrets.

I would insert a verb there.

The inversion is fine even though it is old fashioned, to say the least.

Comment: OP is asking about *he be who* vs. *be he who*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat The inversion is: "trustworthy must he be" versus "he must be trustworthy". I am saying that it is OK as is. There is no need for what he asks, therefore, I didn't address it.

Answer (score 0):

The original version is a generic statement appropriate when a search is underway for such a person. The second version is more likely to happen when the conversation is about whether to allow a particular someone those secrets. I have no problem letting *allow* carry the verb's business forward here if it is in the context of joining a secret handshake society or something similar. It may be more about the potential to learn the secrets rather than the immediate revealing of them.